# Discord bot embed message in command handler issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was playing around with discord bot when my code is starting to get out of hand because there was too much code. So I decided to do some command handling.

First I tried to do it with my ping command but it didn't seem to work.

The `main.js`:

```
const config = require("./config.json");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { clientUser } = require("discord.js");
const clients = new Discord.Client({ intents: 14087});
const prefix = "-scp ";
var version = '1.6.6';
const packageJSON = require("./package.json");
const fs = require(`fs`);
const commandFiles= fs.readdirSync('./commands/')
                      .filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  clients.commands.set(command.name,command)
}

clients.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  try{
    if( message.content == prefix + "ping" ){
    clients.commands.get('ping').execute(message,args);
}
```

the file for "ping" is ping.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name:'ping',
    description:"ping command",
    execute(message,args){
       
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("Pong! ")
          .setDescription("clients's latency: " + 
                     `**${message.createdTimestamp - Date.now()}ms**` + 
                     "\n" + `API's Latency: **${Math.round(clients.ws.ping)}ms**`)
          .setColor('RANDOM');
channel.send({embeds: [embed]});

    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\1love\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-MEST1TS)\Desktop\Bot Core Assets\SCP bot assets\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^
> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\1love\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-MEST1TS)\Desktop\Bot Core Assets\SCP bot assets\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\1love\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-MEST1TS)\Desktop\Bot Core Assets\SCP bot assets\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\1love\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-MEST1TS)\Desktop\Bot Core Assets\SCP bot assets\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:171:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/417093499167440896/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rookie error, you try sending `embed` before it's defined:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle("Pong! ")
   .setDescription("clients's latency: " 
       + `**${message.createdTimestamp - Date.now()}ms**` 
       + "\n" + `API's Latency: **${Math.round(clients.ws.ping)}ms**`)
   .setColor('RANDOM');
channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
```

Comment: Don't you need `content: " "` for sending a message too?

Comment: content is not required whenever sending an embed on it's own

Comment: didn't really resolve the issue but thanks tho(I edited the message)

Comment: You sure? Every time when I tried to send an embed only (without `content: " "`) I got an **Discord API Error - Cannot send empty message**

Comment: @Toasty using 13.1.0 I've been able to send an embed without a `content` option. @some kid playing js what version of DJS are you running?

Comment: @Elitezen Im running on 13.1.0

Comment: I'm using 13.0 I belive.. did they change it again so you can send it without `content: " "` now?

Comment: I just noticed, you're trying to send a message to `channel` which you haven't defined. However this should throw a typeerror, not a discord api error. Are you sure the ping command is the file emitting the error?

Comment: @Toasty as of 13.1.0 most likely, I didn't use 13.0.0

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll have to test that later ...

Comment: as a kid starting out coding discord js bots I have no idea what you are talking about 

Comment: We can't help you much then. I recommend you check all the files that send a message. The error is most likely not coming from your ping command

Comment: lol do you use discord? I wanna sent the whole file to you